# Script to scan log files and send alert when an ip have too many errors (let's say 50) in a period of time (let's say 5 minutes)

Tags: python

I need some help on a python script that requires to scan a logs file: the script should Identify and return (or send an alert to a certain email address) the IPs in the log files that have too many errors within a certain time-frame (let's say 5 minutes). The script should run continuously and should alert every time the condition for sending an email is satisfied.

Log format is:

```
2019-09-02 10:11:12 ERROR 10.12.46.2 user1 ...
2019-09-02 10:11:12 INFO message ...
2019-09-02 10:11:12 ERROR unexpected ...
```

Parsing, counting logs and sending emails is not an issue, but what about the function to calculate those 5 minutes interval? I created some sample code to tackle the log parsing but not the time interval requirement (yet), as I am looking at a simple solution and the one I have in mind ain't.

```
import re
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from datetime import datetime


class Logerrors():       #, max_errors=5, interval=60):
    def __init__(self,filename, top_ip, max_errors, interval):
        self.filename = filename
        self.top_ip = top_ip
        self.max_errors = max_errors
        self.interval = interval

    def logs_parsing(self):
        ips = []
        ips_dates = {}
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                ips_1 = re.search(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (ERROR) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',line)
                if ips_1:
                    ips.append(ips_1.group(3))
                    if ips_1.group(3) not in ips_dates:
                        ips_dates[ips_1.group(3)] = [ips_1.group(1)]
                    else:
                        ips_dates[ips_1.group(3)].append(ips_1.group(1))

        count = Counter(ips)                        # Dictionary
        print(count)
        top_count = count.most_common(self.top_ip)  # List of tuple
        #print(top_count)
        print(f'These are the {self.top_ip} most common IPs')
        for k,v in top_count:
            print(f'{k} ----> {v}')
        return ips_dates

    def most_frequent(self, frequencies):
        print(frequencies)

    def main():
        #pass parameters to class
        messages = Logerrors("./logfile.txt", 3, 50, 5)
        frequencies = messages.logs_parsing()
        messages.most_frequent(frequencies)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The code above is part of my experiment to figure out and does not follow the requirement, but this a sample output that may help to visualize the problem:

```
Counter({'10.12.46.2': 2, '10.12.46.4': 2, '10.12.46.5': 2, '10.12.46.3': 1})
These are the 3 most common IPs
10.12.46.2 ----> 2
10.12.46.4 ----> 2
10.12.46.5 ----> 2
{'10.12.46.2': ['2019-09-02 10:11:12', '2019-09-02 10:11:12'], '10.12.46.3': ['2019-09-02 10:11:13'], '10.12.46.4': ['2019-09-02 10:11:14', '2019-09-02 10:11:15'], '10.12.46.5': ['2019-09-02 10:11:16', '2019-09-02 10:11:17']}
```

The place where I am stuck is how to programmatically monitor the log files for finding the IPs with errors within 5 minutes.

Few ideas that need validation:

1. The `log_parsing` method should have a while loop so to continuously read the logs (in the current version would read them once) assuming that the script should always run and so always scan the logs file provided.
2. In the dict `frequencies`:

   ```
   {'10.12.46.2': ['2019-09-02 10:11:12', '2019-09-02 10:11:12'],
    '10.12.46.4': ['2019-09-02 10:11:14', '2019-09-02 10:11:15'],
    '10.12.46.5': ['2019-09-02 10:11:16', '2019-09-02 10:11:17']}
   ```

I have key-value pairs of "IPs -> list of dates the error occur": In order to satisfy the requirement I could monitor and check at every iteration if the length of the value for each key whose value is updated is > 50 and then do some date and time arithmetic to calculate if the threshold is reached within 5 minutes: is this the right approach or is there an easier one?

Comment: You could run your code in a while loop with `sleep(300)` to sleep for 5 minutes. Then just search for logs within the last 5 minutes and `len()` dict values and action anything over `len(50)`?

Comment: I could, but then I would miss error count > 50 happening adding errors in two contiguous  5 minutes interval (e.g. 51 errors form the same IP between minute 3 and minute 8. Thanks